# Show stock status next to each attribute value in WooCommerce variable products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stock, product-variations

I want to implement in my store something similar like this:

[image]

I have this code, but this show quantity next to each variation.

```
function get_stock_variations_from_product(){
global $product;
$variations = $product->get_available_variations();
foreach($variations as $variation){
     $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
     $variation_obj = new WC_Product_variation($variation_id);
     $stock = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();
}
}
```

And also this code:

```
  global $product;
$product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

foreach ($product_variations as $variation)  {
    $var_data = $variation['attributes'];
    $var_data['in_stock'] = $variation['is_in_stock'];
}

//List all attributes with stock available or not array..
echo '<pre>';
print_r($var_data);
echo '</pre>';
die;
```

How can I customize the variable products to show stock Status next to each attribute values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Faster and optimized code version for WooCommerce 3+ only in:
 [Display variation stock status on single dropdown variable products in Wocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65002729/display-variation-stock-status-on-single-dropdown-variable-products-in-wocommerc/65007899#65007899)

---

**Updated WooCommerce compatibility** or previous version 2.6.x

You can do it using a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_variation_option_name`** filter hook. This is only viable for products that have a unique attribute for their variations…

Here is the code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'customizing_variations_terms_name', 10, 1 );
function customizing_variations_terms_name( $term_name ){

    if(is_admin())
        return $term_name;

    global $product;
    $second_loop_stoped = false;

    // Get available product variations
    $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

    // Iterating through each available product variation
    foreach($product_variations as $variation){

        $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
        $variation_obj = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );

        ## WOOCOMMERCE RETRO COMPATIBILITY ##
        if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ) # BEFORE Version 3 (older)
        {
            $stock_status = $variation_obj->stock_status;
            $stock_qty = intval($variation_obj->stock);

            // The attributes WC slug key and slug value for this variation
            $attributes_arr = $variation_obj->get_variation_attributes();
        }
        else # For newest verions: 3.0+ (and Up)
        {
            $stock_status = $variation_obj->get_stock_status();
            $stock_qty = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();

            // The attributes taxonomy key and slug value for this variation
            $attributes_arr = $variation_obj->get_attributes();
        }

        if(count($attributes_arr) != 1) // Works only for 1 attribute set in the product
            return $term_name;

        // Get the terms for this attribute
        foreach( $attributes_arr as $attr_key => $term_slug){
            // Get the attribute taxonomy
            $term_key = str_replace('attribute_', '', $attr_key );

            // get the corresponding term object
            $term_obj = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $term_key );
            if( $term_obj->name == $term_name ){ // If the term name matches we stop the loops
                $second_loop_stoped = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if($second_loop_stoped)
            break;
    }
    if( $stock_qty>0 )
        return $term_name .= ' - ' . $stock_status . ' ('.$stock_qty.')';
    else
        return $term_name .= ' - ' . $stock_status;

}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

> This code works and is tested in WooCommerce 2.6.x and 3+.

---

You will get this (for example):

[image]

> You can use other WC_Product_Variation or [WC_Product](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html) methods to get and display the data you want…