# Show "Out of Stock" text , next to variation in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

I Would like next to variation to show "Out of Stock" when product variation is out of stock. Below, I am using the code from [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037405/show-stock-status-next-to-each-attribute-value-in-woocommerce-variable-products/45041602#45041602):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 
'customizing_variations_terms_name', 10, 1 );
function customizing_variations_terms_name( $term_name ){

if(is_admin())
    return $term_name;

global $product;
$second_loop_stoped = false;

// Get available product variations
$product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

// Iterating through each available product variation
foreach($product_variations as $variation){

    $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
    $variation_obj = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );

    ## WOOCOMMERCE RETRO COMPATIBILITY ##
    if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ) # BEFORE Version 3 (older)
    {
        $stock_status = $variation_obj->stock_status;
        $stock_qty = intval($variation_obj->stock);

        // The attributes WC slug key and slug value for this variation
        $attributes_arr = $variation_obj->get_variation_attributes();
    }
    else # For newest verions: 3.0+ (and Up)
    {
        $stock_status = $variation_obj->get_stock_status();
        $stock_qty = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();

        // The attributes taxonomy key and slug value for this variation
        $attributes_arr = $variation_obj->get_attributes();
    }

    if(count($attributes_arr) != 1) // Works only for 1 attribute set in the product
        return $term_name;

    // Get the terms for this attribute
    foreach( $attributes_arr as $attr_key => $term_slug){
        // Get the attribute taxonomy
        $term_key = str_replace('attribute_', '', $attr_key );

        // get the corresponding term object
        $term_obj = get_term_by( 'slug', $term_slug, $term_key );
        if( $term_obj->name == $term_name ){ // If the term name matches we stop the loops
            $second_loop_stoped = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($second_loop_stoped)
        break;
}
if( $stock_qty>0 )
    return $term_name .= ' - ' . $stock_status . ' ('.$stock_qty.')';
else
    return $term_name .= ' - ' . $stock_status;

}
```

but when test on my site, it show "Out of Stock" for all variations i have on selected product. For example on this [product](https://www.fruit.co.il/en/catalog/ananas-comosus/) it show "Out of Stock" for all variations i have, but in fact, only variation "50 ליטר" is in real "Out Of Stock". other variations are In Stock ! I using Woocommerce 3.3.5 version. Can someone to tell me what i need to do to show out of stock next to variations if product is out of stock for real, because i m using radio buttons as replacement for standard dropdown button from Woocommerce.

Comment: See what i have for variation 10.. https://i.imgur.com/q5IJYeX.png?1 Its in Stock , but when load product page, it shown for all out of stock. ?

Comment: I using radio buttons for variations, not standard dropdown menu. Your answer not working on my site. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 2):

Seems over complicated, I managed to do it this way.  Seems to work, displays out of stock for the correct variations when I tested it.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'customizing_variations_terms_name', 10, 1 );

function customizing_variations_terms_name( $term_name ) {

    global $product;
    // Get available product variations
    $product_variations = $product->get_available_variations();

    // product_variation terms are normalized to lowercase with
    // spaces replaced by dashes.
    // if your term name contains capital letters or spaces i.e. 'SIZE 6'
    // the product variation will be lowercase with dashes, i.e. 'size-6'
    /*
         $term_name = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower($term_name));
    */

    foreach ( $product_variations as $product_variation ) {
        if( isset( $product_variation['attributes'] ) ) {
            $key = array_search($term_name, $product_variation['attributes']);

            if( $key !== false && ! $product_variation['is_in_stock'] ) {
                return $term_name . ' - Out of Stock';
            }
        }
    }

    return $term_name;
}
```

In addition to this you can grey out the product so they can't select it if that's something that are after.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 'grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock', 10, 2 );

function grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock( $grey_out, $variation ) {

    if ( ! $variation->is_in_stock() )
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: See what gives to me when apply your first function.. Not showing out of stock for me.

Comment: Seems that your code dont updated any changes.. CAn you take a look ?

Comment: This works in the shop but crashes admin product editing! Any fix for this

Comment: if( !is_admin() ) { } does the trick