# Display variation stock status on single dropdown variable products in Wocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, taxonomy-terms, product-variations

I am using [Show stock status next to each attribute value in WooCommerce variable products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037405/show-stock-status-next-to-each-attribute-value-in-woocommerce-variable-products/45041602#45041602) answer code to display the variation stock status on single product attribute dropdown for variable product pages.

This works fine, but take too much time to load a product.

How could I optimize the code to make it load faster?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following instead, that will be a bit lighter *(so variable products should load quickly)*:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'customizing_variations_terms_name' );
function customizing_variations_terms_name( $term_name ){
    global $product;

    if( is_admin() ) return $term_name; // Only on frontend single products

    // Iterating through each visible product variation Ids
    foreach( $product->get_visible_children() as $variation_id ){
        $variation = new WC_Product_Variation( $variation_id );

        $stock_status = $variation->get_stock_status();
        $stock_qty    = $variation->get_stock_quantity();

            // The attributes taxonomy key and slug value for this variation
            $attributes = $variation->get_attributes();

        // Caution: Works only for 1 attribute set in the product
        if(count($attributes) == 1 ) {
            $attributes_keys = array_keys($attributes);
            $attr_taxonomy   = str_replace('attribute_', '', reset($attributes_keys) );
            if( $variation->get_attribute( $attr_taxonomy ) === $term_name ) {
                break; // stop the loop
            }
        }
        $term_name .= ' - ' . $stock_status;
        $term_name  = $stock_qty > 0 ? $term_name . ' ('.$stock_qty.')' : $term_name;
    }
    return $term_name;
}
```

Comment: I have 4 attributes and stock depends on the fourth, shoud i do something special ?