# Showing "Out of Stock" text next to variation in Woocommerce product with multuiple variations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I have been looking EVERYWHERE and I cannot seem to find a solution to a very simple problem. I have a Woocommerce store and I want to show to the user a message "Out of stock" next to the variation if it is out of stock. I do not want it grayed out, I want the user to be able to select it so they can view the price if they wish. Most snippets I find online only works when they product has ONE variation but I need it to work for at least two. My website sells mobile devices so for example:

If a user selects the storage as 64GB then the color list updates showing which colors are out of stock in 64GB. If all colors are out of stock then next to 64GB it shows "Out of stock" also.

If the color is selected first, then the storage - the color list is then updated with what is out of stock.

Can anyone help me out here? Going insane trying to get this working. The below code works to gray out out of stock products in the exact way I mentioned above (it works for multiple products) but I can't figure out how to modify it for the use case mentioned above.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_is_active', 'grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock', 10, 2 );
function grey_out_variations_when_out_of_stock( $grey_out, $variation ){
if ( ! $variation->is_in_stock() ){
  return false;
 }else{
print_r($option_class);
  return $term_name . ' - Out of Stock';;
 }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add variation stock status to Woocommerce product variation dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180058/how-to-add-variation-stock-status-to-woocommerce-product-variation-dropdown)

Comment: You can't do this using PHP. At least one option of an attribute must be selected to be able to check the stock status of all possible combinations (variations). You will then need to use jQuery.

Comment: @Bhautik This answer will only work for variable products with 1 dropdown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check the availability of a product variation **only if all but one of the attributes have been selected**, not before.

All the necessary data is present on the product page and therefore you can use a jQuery script to process it.

In the variation form there is the `data-product_variations` attribute which contains an array with all the details of the product variations (variation id, stock status, attributes it uses, etc ...).

You can then make a comparison between the selected attributes and possible product variations.

The idea is this:

1. Check that there is more than one attribute (dropdown) on the product page
2. If all attributes (dropdowns) have been selected except one, **get the attribute slug and the attribute value of the selected options**
3. It compares them with the attributes that each single variation uses and, if the selected attributes are the same, **gets the stock status of the last attribute to be selected**
4. Adds the text *"Out of stock"* to each option whose product variation is not in stock. To do this it will use the `woocommerce_update_variation_values` event which fires after updating the options via Ajax (otherwise the changes will be overwritten)

> The following code will work for 2 or more attributes (dropdowns) in
> the variable product page.

```
// add the text "Out of stock" to each option of the last unselected attribute dropdown
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'add_out_of_stock_text_to_the_last_unselected_attribute_dropdown' );
function add_out_of_stock_text_to_the_last_unselected_attribute_dropdown() {

    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    // initializes a global variable that will contain the attribute values to be updated ("Out of stock")
    let globalAttributesToUpdate;

    jQuery(function($){

        // check if only one attribute is missing to be selected
        function isLastAttribute(){
            // if there is only one dropdown it returns false
            if ( $('form.variations_form select').length == 1 ) {
                return false;
            }
            // counts all selected attributes (excluding "Choose an option")
            let count = 0;
            $('form.variations_form select').each(function(){
                if ( $(this).find(':selected').val() ) {
                    count++;
                }
            });
            // if an attribute has not yet been selected, it returns true
            if ( $('form.variations_form select').length - count == 1 ) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        $('form.variations_form select').change(function() {
            if ( isLastAttribute() ) {
                // clear the global variable every time
                globalAttributesToUpdate = [];
                let attrToFind = {}; // contains an object with slug and value of the selected attributes
                let attrToSet; // contains the slug of the attribute not yet selected
                $('form.variations_form select').each(function(index,object){
                    if ( $(this).find(":selected").val() ) {
                        attrToFind[$(this).data('attribute_name')] = $(this).find(":selected").val();
                    } else {
                        attrToSet = $(this).data('attribute_name');
                    }
                });
                // gets the value of the "data-product_variations" attribute of the variations form
                let variationData = $('form.variations_form').data("product_variations");
                $(variationData).each(function(index,object) {
                    let attrVariation = object.attributes;
                    let attrVariationLenght = Object.keys(attrVariation).length;
                    let found = 0;
                    let toSet;
                    let valueToSet;
                    // check all possible combinations of attributes (for single variation)
                    // based on the selected attributes
                    $.each( attrVariation, function( attr, value ) {
                        if ( attr in attrToFind && attrToFind[attr] == value ) {
                            found++;
                        } else {
                            // if the variation is out of stock it gets slug and value to add the text "Out of stock"
                            if ( object.is_in_stock == false ) {
                                toSet = attr;
                                valueToSet = value;
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    // if only one attribute is missing
                    if ( attrVariationLenght - found == 1 ) {
                        if ( toSet == attrToSet ) {
                            let obj = {};
                            obj[toSet] = valueToSet;
                            globalAttributesToUpdate.push(obj);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        // inserts the text "Out of stock" after updating the variations
        // based on the "globalAttributesToUpdate" global variable
        $('body').on('woocommerce_update_variation_values', function(){
            if ( globalAttributesToUpdate !== undefined && globalAttributesToUpdate.length ) {
                $.each( globalAttributesToUpdate, function( key, attribute ) {
                    $.each( attribute, function( attrName, attrValue ) {
                        $('select[name='+attrName+'] > option[value="'+attrValue+'"]').append( " (Out of stock)" );
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php

}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

**RESULT**

[image]

**RELATED ANSWERS**

- [How to add variation stock status to Woocommerce product variation dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47180058/how-to-add-variation-stock-status-to-woocommerce-product-variation-dropdown)
- [Show stock status next to each attribute value in WooCommerce variable products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45037405/show-stock-status-next-to-each-attribute-value-in-woocommerce-variable-products)
- [Display variation stock status on single dropdown variable products in Wocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65002729/display-variation-stock-status-on-single-dropdown-variable-products-in-wocommerc)

Comment: Your code works fantastic!! It's exactly what I had in mind. Thank you SO much. I have one additional question:

Would it be possible to add the out of stock text for the 2nd variation if ALL variations are out of stock based on the first selected variation?

For example, a phone has two attributes: storage and color. The user selects their required storage but ALL variations are out of stock so immediately the storage shows out of stock text next to it

Comment: Hi, thanks for your code @vincenzo. Is this only working for product that are out of stock? What about products that are on backorder? I would like to add a text like "on backorder" to that as well. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

```html
add_filter('woocommerce_variation_option_name', 'display_price_in_variation_option_name');
function display_price_in_variation_option_name($term)
{
    global $wpdb, $product;
    $result = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT slug FROM {$wpdb->prefix}terms WHERE name = '$term'");
    $term_slug = (!empty($result)) ? $result[0] : $term;
    $query = "SELECT postmeta.post_id AS product_id
                FROM {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS postmeta
                    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}posts AS products ON ( products.ID = postmeta.post_id )
                WHERE postmeta.meta_key LIKE 'attribute_%'
                    AND postmeta.meta_value = '$term_slug'
                    AND products.post_parent = $product->id";
    $variation_id = $wpdb->get_col($query);
    $parent = wp_get_post_parent_id($variation_id[0]);
    if ($parent > 0) {
        $_product = new WC_Product_Variation($variation_id[0]);
        $_currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
        $stock = $_product->is_in_stock() ? 'instock' : 'out of stock';
        return $term . ' (' . $_product->get_price()  . ' ' . $_currency . ') &nbsp;- &nbsp;' . $stock;
    }
    return $term;
}
```